# Is Isaiah 27.9 in reference to the expiation of Jacob's iniquity by the altar's destruction in 70 CE?

Tags: isaiah

Is Isaiah 27.9 in reference to the expiation of Jacob's iniquity by the altar's destruction in 70 CE?

> Isaiah 27.9: 
>   Therefore by this shall the iniquity of Jacob be expiated, And this is all the fruit of taking away his sin: When he maketh all the stones of the altar as chalkstones that are beaten in pieces, So that the Asherim and the sun-images shall rise no more.

Answer (score 2):

I have always understood this passage as referring to the destruction of the first temple, and the rest of the city, in Nebuchadnezzar's third campaign (ending about 586 BC).  It was then that the altars were destroyed, the temple furniture removed.

I say this on the basis that Isa 27:9 also mentions that following this destruction of the temple and its altars that Asherim and sun-images will be seen no more.  When the Jews returned under Zerubbabel (about 537 BC) until the final destruction of the temple in 70 AD, for all the faults of the Jews, there was never any Asherim or sun-images.

Therefore, Isa 27:9 is a reference to the destruction of the first temple and not the second temple.  The rest of the Isa 27 appears to have the same reference.  However, v6 appears to look beyond the destruction of the fist temple to the time when Judah would be restored in the land.  Both prophecies were fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a clear no.

The altar's destruction in 70 CE is prophesied by Jesus in Matthew 24:2

> "Do you see all these things?" he asked. "Truly I tell you, not one stone here will be left on another; every one will be thrown down."

Jesus often cites Hebrew scriptures of prophecies. In this case, He didn't. He didn't say that the 70 CE destruction was related to Isaiah 27.9. More importantly, He explicitly says that the 70 CE destruction is related to Him in Luke 19

> 41 As he approached Jerusalem and saw the city, he wept over it 42 and said, “If you, even you, had only known on this day what would bring you peace—but now it is hidden from your eyes. 43 The days will come upon you when your enemies will build an embankment against you and encircle you and hem you in on every side. 44 They will dash you to the ground, you and the children within your walls. They will not leave one stone on another, because you did not recognize the time of God’s coming to you.”

The reason that the temple was destroyed is because the Jews didn't see Him as the Son of God and not because of the preexilic sins committed by the Kingdoms of Israel and Judah. At best the Isaiah 27.9 prophecy is a foreshadow to Matthew 24:2.

Comment: but Jesus' so called prediction has no bearing on this question since he was a false prophet who falsely claimed in Matthew 16.28 that he would restore the kingdom to Israel. Since that did not happen as Acts 1.6-7 demonstrates, he was a false prophet who deserved the death penalty

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti It seems you are not alone in your accusation : there was a whole multitude who cried out Crucify him ! Crucify Him !.

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti - Matt 16:28 says: "Truly I tell you, some who are standing here will not taste death before they see the Son of Man coming in his kingdom.  This was fulfilled only a few days later in Matt 17 with the transfiguration.

Comment: @Dottard wrong again. if so; then why did his disciples ask him in Acts 1.6-7 when the kingdom would be restored to Israel? Since the kingdom was not restored to Israel "BEFORE" the death of his disciples as Acts 1.6-7 demonstrates, he was a false prophet who deserved the death penalty!

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti - they are two different questions